# Can't figure out where these C# and Java code differ

Tags: c#, java, apache-commons

I have some C# code that converts an image to base64 string. The code is :

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Image img = Image.FromFile(filename);
img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
string s = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.GetBuffer());
```

I am trying to implement it with JAVA. my java code is :

```
BufferedImage img = null;
img = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
byte[] bytes = ((DataBufferByte)img.getData().getDataBuffer()).getData();
String js = Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes);
```

this two piece of code should return the same string for the same image file. But they are returning different strings. I am unable to figure out why. Can anyone shed some light on it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> this two piece of code should return the same string for the same image file

No, they really shouldn't.

The C# code is returning the base64 representation of a JPEG-encoded version of the image data - and potentially some 0s at the end, as you're using `GetBuffer` instead of `ToArray`. (You want `ToArray` here.)

The Java code is returning the base64 representation of the raw raster data, according to its `SampleModel`. I'd expect this to be significantly larger than the string returned by the C# code.

Even if both pieces of code encoded the image with the same format, that doesn't mean they'll come up with the exact same data - it will depend on the encoding.

Importantly, if you just want "the contents of the file in base64" then you don't need to go via an `Image` at all. For example, in C# you could use:

```
string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(filename));
```

The fact that it's an image is irrelevant in that respect - the file is just a collection of bytes, and you can base64-encode that without understanding the meaning of those bytes at all.

Comment: can you give any suggestion on how I can improve the JAVA code so that it returns the same string as the C# one?

Comment: @th1rdey3: I've given a better (IMO) alternative to *either* of the pieces of code you've got at the moment, assuming the image file is already in the format you want.

Comment: I actually need to implement the C# code. So it can't change. I need to change the JAVA code so that it produces the same result.

Comment: @th1rdey3: Then you're out of luck, I suspect. Unless the image is already in jpeg format and the .NET libraries detect that and *don't* re-encode (unlikely), you'd need to find an encoder which worked in *exactly* the same way as the .NET library. It's like encoding a sound file twice with different MP3 encoders and expecting to get a bit-for-bit identical result. (As an aside, it's Java not JAVA.)